# How to create buffer, when i get RTSP stream by ffmpeg?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm getting video stream from rtsp with ffmpeg on C. I'm writing it to file directly.
I need to create 10 sec buffer, where i can hold last 10 sec video from rtsp sream. And at one moment i need to start record all video from rtsp to file (including this 10 sec buffer before).
Can anybody tell me, how to do it?

Comment: "I'm getting video stream from rtsp with ffmpeg on C." provide this snipped

Comment: If you know enough C to retrieve an RTSP stream and dump it to a file, I doubt you really ask for how to allocate memory in C, do you? Sorry, but this question is far too unspecific to answer, could you explain more detailed what you do and give the code which does it?

Answer (score 4):

`malloc` yourself a circular buffer large enough to hold 20 sec of data, and `push` your stream data into it (constantly overwriting data that is too old).

When your event of interest happens, simply `pop` the full 10 sec before and 10 sec of interest to a `FILE*` writer of your choice.

***Edit:***
Dilon is right, if you want simultaneous I/O, add the necessary complexity as he indicates.

If simply wanting the data as asked with no extra data after the 10 seconds in question, just halt your writer into the circular buffer when your event of interest happens, and you're done :)

Answer (score 1):

Gunther has a good approach, and that will work for your problem, but you risk overwriting data if you temporarily write too much faster than you read it (maybe the read got stalled for some reason?), or stalling to to wait for data reads.

To fix this, I'd suggest making a few buffers of reasonable size, and then create a linked list to contain pointers to the buffers. Once one buffer is filled, remove it from the current LL to a `full` LL, and start buffering into the next available buffer. As you read buffers from the `full` LL, move them back to the `empty` LL. If you run out of buffers in the `full` LL- just `malloc()` another one.

This way, you have one queue of buffers to read, one to write, and if there's an issue of availability- just add more buffers. No risk of overwriting data prematurely.

Comment: I see that you would avoid overwriting data, but how is this supposed to include less pointer fiddling than a ring buffer?

Comment: It doesn't- you are right. I changed my answer midway through from using 2 fixed buffers: read/write, to allow for extra buffers to prevent overflow. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes- usually when I have to implement a circular buffer (and memory isn't an issue), I have two separate buffers behind the scenes to simplify things a tad. That's how that artifact worked its way into my response initially.